# What is the equivalent of .hide() that keeps the place in the layout?

Tags: jquery

When using `.hide()`, the element is no more participating in the layout of the page.
But what if I want to keep its place, i.e I don't want other elements to move because this one is hidden now.
How could I do this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
element.css('visibility', 'hidden')
```

To undo:

```
element.css('visibility', 'visible')
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer !

Answer (score 3):

You could try animating the opacity - something like:

```
$('your selector').animate({
    opacity: 0 /* 0 = hide() ; 1 = show() */
}, 700);
```